# Error with creating a FeedElement with an attachment: You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request

Tags: rest-api, chatter, error

I'm using the code below to create a feed element with an attachment, using Apache's HttpClient and Chatter REST API, v32.0.

```
    File feedElementDefinition = new File("feed3.txt");
    String json = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(feedElementDefinition));

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
        "https://eu3.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/chatter/feed-elements" +
        "?feedElementType=FeedItem" +
        "&subjectId=<id of my user account>" +
        "&text=Text"
    );
    post.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token());
    post.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.getMimeType());
    post.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, ContentType.WILDCARD.getMimeType());
    post.setEntity(
        MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
            .addBinaryBody(
                "feedElementFileUpload",
                new File("feed_element.txt"),
                ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
                "feed_element.txt"
            )
            .addTextBody(
                "json",
                json,
                ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON
            ).build()
    );
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Contents of `feed3.txt` are:

```
{
  "body" : {
    "messageSegments" : [ {
      "text" : "Some dummy status",
      "type" : "Text"
    } ]
  },
  "capabilities" : {
    "associatedActions" : null,
    "bookmarks" : {
      "isBookmarkedByCurrentUser" : false
    },
    "content" : {
      "description" : "feed_file",
      "title" : "feed3.txt"
    }
  },  
  "feedElementType" : "FeedItem",
  "originalFeedElementId" : null,
  "visibility" : "AllUsers",
  "subjectId" : "<my user account id>"
}
```

However, it fails with the following message:

```
You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request.
```

What's the reason for this? I'm going almost crazy on this one, since when I use cURL (show below), it's fine.

```
curl -H "X-PrettyPrint: 1" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F 'json={ "body" : { "messageSegments" : [ { "text" : "Some dummy status", "type" : "Text" } ] }, "capabilities" : { "associatedActions" : null, "bookmarks" : { "isBookmarkedByCurrentUser" : false }, "content" : { "description" : "feed_file", "title" : "feed3" } },  "feedElementType" : "FeedItem", "originalFeedElementId" : null, "visibility" : "AllUsers", "subjectId" : "my_user_account_id" };type=application/json' -F "feedElementFileUpload=@/home/haris/projects/open-source/java-playground/feed3.txt;type=application/octet-stream" 
-X POST 'https://eu3.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/chatter/feed-elements?feedElementType=FeedItem&subjectId=my_user_account_id&text=Text' -H 'Authorization: OAuth my_token_blah_blah' --insecure
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with how Apache's HttpClient should be called. The solution is to remove the following line:

```
post.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.getMimeType());
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273942/improperly-formatted-request-error-after-switching-from-commons-httpclient-to).